How to get custom span attributes into datadog dashboard
I have some spans that have attributes, and when I view them in datadog APM traces I can see the values in span info:
{
    ... rest of attributes
    webhook {
        event: <some event>
        id <some id>
        topic: <some-topic>
    }
}

When i try to add these as a column with the "add column for @webhook.topic" in my APM traces the column is always empty.

When I try to use this information on a dashboard by using APM @webhook.topic nothing shows up as well.
I have APM retentions configured for this service.
